# Labeling coordinate value at 4 corners of graticule in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, grids-graticules

Is it possible to label automatically lat/long values at 4 corners: upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right of the graticule in Arcgis (10)?

I have not found the way to do that so far.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by graticule.  Are you talking about the mouse cursor or a feature on the map?  A picture would probably be a big help.

Comment: I think, in ArcGIS, there is the option to produce grids, whereas a measured grid is going to be based off a PCS (or arbitrary units with a custom point of origin) using x/y or often metres as its base unit, a graticule will use lat/lon or dd/dms for its units

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS 10.0 you can do this at an ArcView license level using dynamic text.  See the following help topic: 
 http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Working_with_dynamic_text/00s900000013000000/

If you scroll down to the section on Coordinate system dynamic text you will find the syntax for the text element for each of the four corners of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to automatically label, in a graticule grid the corner points based on the extent of the current map. A suggested workflow: create an extent polygon from your current extent, convert polygon to points, generate x/y or lat/lon coordinates in a new field(s) then label those points based on that field.

In a measured grid, you can label 'corners' which in this case is only the grid line closest to the corner, not the actual corner *point*.
[image: CornerLabelSettingsArcGIS931]

Answer (score 1):

Try the
The Make Grids and Graticules Layers

*"Creates a grouped layer of feature classes depicting grid, graticule, and border features using predefined cartographic specifications. Grid layers are ideal for advanced grid definitions which are scale and extent specific."*

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00700000001n000000.htm

Comment: This works if you have ArcEditor or ArcInfo licensing, still leaves the ArcView users out in the cold, again. I would imagine that at the arcview level, similarly this could be done after the grid is built, to convert to graphics (you would get a border with four corners) then back to shapefile.